# What is the best way to check if a group of points is inside a cube shape you create using eight points for the each of the corners?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plane

What is the best way to check if a group of points is inside a cube shape you create using eight points for the each of the corners?

So, what is happening is I am using these "Planes" in place for a test. but the test is not producing completely valid results. Some are in and some that should be in are not and sometimes some that should not be in are in.

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    private struct SelectionPoints
    {
        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneNearTL;
        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneFarTL;

        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneNearBR;
        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneFarBR;

        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneNearTR;
        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneFarTR;

        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneNearBL;
        public Vector3 SelectoionPlaneFarBL;
    }

    private void methodName(Vector3 pos)
    {
        SelectionPoints _selectionPoints;

        //...
        //code to fill in _selectionPoints
        //...

        Plane planeTop = new Plane(_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTL,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearTL);
        Plane planeRight = new Plane(_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarBR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearTR,selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTR);
        Plane planeBottom = new Plane(selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarBL,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearBR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarBR);
        Plane planeLeft = new Plane(_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarBL,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearTL,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTL);
        Plane planeNear = new Plane(_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearBR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearTR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearTL);
        Plane planeFar = new Plane(selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTL,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarBR);

        if (
            (planeTop.GetSide(point)) &&
            (planeBottom.GetSide(point)) &&
            (planeRight.GetSide(point)) &&
            (planeLeft.GetSide(point)) &&
            (planeNear.GetSide(point)) &&
            (planeFar.GetSide(point))
            )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want from us?? I'm so confused now. :|

Comment: Sorry it's not vertices its points. I guess what I'm asking is to check my code to see if a group of points are within a shape defined by eight points.

Comment: OK, now i understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity3d a plane is an infinitely large, flat surface that exists in 3D space and divides the space into two halves known as half-spaces and you can use `GetSide()` to determine which of the two half-spaces a particular point is in and also how far the point is from the plane.

Also a plane can also be defined by the three corner points of a triangle that lies within the plane. In this case, the **normal vector** points toward you if the corner points go around **clockwise** as you look at the triangle **face-on**.

[image: plane]

So first of all I'm assuming you have a typo in your code that the Vector3 you use in your checking process is called `point` but your input as a function in called `pos`.

But the main problem here is the `planeRight` defenition that should be this:

```
Plane planeRight = new Plane(_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarBR,selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneFarTR,_selectionPoints.SelectoionPlaneNearTR);
```

in this form the normal vector going to be in the correct position.

hope this solve your problem.